# List of available RTML books and resources

Tags: yahoo, rtml

I'm dealing with RTML at work a lot. When I was just starting to learn RTML it was extremely hard for me to find any useful resources and good books on the topic.

The best book I'm found so far is this one:

**RTML 101: The Unofficial Guideto Yahoo! Store Templates**
http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/ytimes/rtmlintro.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a lot of info on the web about RTML out there unfortunately. . . Here are a couple more resources ->

This forum has a wealth of information about yahoo stores, and most people in the RTML business subscribe to it.
http://www.yourstoreforums.com/

This tool can be used to transfer RTML templates, for a price.
http://software.yourstorewizards.com/rtml/rtmltransfer.msi

Another ebook for beginner RTML
http://www.ytimes.info/cuteno.html

More advanced ebook.
http://www.ytimes.info/decyt.html

I can't give you any RTML templates unfortunately, but I hope these resources can get you off to a good start.

Comment: oops, almost forgot -> http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/edit/advanced/advanced-09.html

Comment: this is a list of all the available RTML books out there -> http://www.ytimes.info/books.html