# How can I import a block of RTML into a yahoo merchant store?

Tags: yahoo, rtml, yahoo-merchant-store

I've put together a block of RTML that i would like to add to a product page. Now that i've got that, I'm trying to figure out how to place that whole block of RTML into the product's template. That may not be the right way to do it.

my desired result is that the html of the product page is rendered PLUS the html that would be rendered by my added block of RTML.'

**What I have tried**: as far as I can tell, i can only use the editor to add RTML 1 line / update at a time. which means anything complicated would take forever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Kristian, you're absolutely right. The operators in RTML take a very, very long time to insert because it requires a page refresh for each operator in the store editor. If you have a lot of HTML to update, you can use the RTML template uploader located here http://www.yourstorewizards.com/rtml-transfer-utility.html . While it is free to "download" templates, you are charged for "uploading" templates. This is because you aren't truly uploading or downloading templates. What the program does is move your mouse around the screen very quickly doing all the clicking for you.

At the very least, you can use the MULTI command to group other commands together. That way you can quickly duplicate operators/HTML. You can take a bunch of TEXT operators and quickly duplicate them inside a MULTI, and then duplicate the MULTI. This is probably one of the most efficient ways to do large blocks of HTML.

Another idea... Print out a script tag using a TEXT operator, and insert your HTML with JavaScript. Obviously you won't want to do this all the time, but if you're looking to insert a very large piece of HTML this may be your best bet.

Comment: Also, a list of books/resources out there on RTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464944/list-of-available-rtml-books-and-resources/5560374#5560374